# ELM : Compile ELM page to JS

Tags: elm

after creating an ELM page and running it successfully using (`elm-reactor`),
I have compiled it to generate the js file and open it using browser.

using the following command : `elm-make pageName.elm --output target.js`.

anyway the target.js page is generated successfully but when opening it using the browser it does not show the desired outcome instead it displays the source code as per the below screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `elm-make pageName.elm` without `--output target.js` and open produced `index.html`

Alternatively, create your own `*.html` file and embed `target.js` via `<script>` tag, as you would normally do it for any other JavaScript files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My app</title>
    <script src="target.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Run the application manually.
      Elm.Target.fullscreen();
    <script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Assuming that the name of the entry module is `Target` and you want it to take over the whole page.

Comment: I think you need to invoke it.  Just loading is not enough.

Comment: @Tosh you are absolutely right, I have updated the example